# Script a test for installed debian package - error handling?

Tags: shell, dpkg

I want to script a test for a debian package being installed.

Searching using `dpkg-query`, will return an error if no packages match.  But if I want to detect that specifically, and abort on any other errors (e.g. resource exhaustion), I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dpkg-query is quite simple, you can quickly skim the manpage and find it has no option to implement this directly.  So

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package} ${State}\n' | grep "^my-package .* installed"
```

The problem then reduces to [catching error codes in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550933/catching-error-codes-in-a-shell-pipe).  Apparently strict error handling in Unix shell gets awkward.  I was naively hoping for one-liners :).

```
set -e

function pkg_is_installed() {
  PKG="$1"
  LISTF=$(mktemp)
  dpkg-query -W -f '${Package} ${State}\n' >$LISTF
  grep "^${PKG} .* installed$" $LISTF >/dev/null   
  GREP_RC=$?
  rm $LISTF

  # for even moar strict error handling
  test $GREP_RC == 0 -o $GREP_RC == 1

  return $GREP_RC
}
```

I believe this will print any errors that occur to stderr, while avoiding printing a message when the only "error" is that dpkg hasn't (yet) seen the requested package.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg-query` does have an option to do this, and its exit codes support your use case:

> **`-s`**, **`--status`** `package-name...`
>
> Report status of specified package. This just displays the  entry  in  the  installed  package  status
>                 database.  When  multiple  `package-name`  are  listed, the requested status entries are separated by an
>                 empty line, with the same order as specified on the argument list.

(note that it looks in the *installed* package status database, so it can't report on anything not installed — which is what you're after);
and

> **EXIT STATUS**
>
> 0:      The requested query was successfully performed.
>
> 1:      The  requested  query  failed either fully or partially, due to no file or package being found (except
>                 for `--control-path`, `--control-list` and `--control-show` were such errors are fatal).
>
> 2:      Fatal or unrecoverable error due to invalid command-line usage, or interactions with the system,  such
>                 as accesses to the database, memory allocations, etc.

(The manpage included in Debian 8 doesn't mention this, but `dpkg-query` does behave like that even in Debian 8.)

So something like

```
#!/bin/sh

dpkg-query -s package > /dev/null 2>&1
case $? in
0)
    echo $1 is installed
    ;;
1)
    echo $1 is not installed
    ;;
2)
    echo An error occurred
    ;;
esac
```

(turned into a function) would fit the bill as I understand it.

Comment: Thanks!  The manpage I looked at was on Debian Jessie.  It does not document the value 2 in the section EXIT STATUS, only 0 and 1.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't checked on Jessie — I just did, and the behaviour is as described above; the manpage is outdated.